# Unable to sort dates in Access with SQL backend

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have an application in Access 2013 with a SQL backend. Its sorts dates like :

```
01/01/2015
01/02/2013
01/02/2014
```

.

The ApplicationDate is stored as a Datetime value in SQL. How do I get it to sort in the right order.

Comment: I don't believe you.  I think the date is stored as a string.

Comment: What do you mean SQL? SQL is a language that even Access uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your data is stored in *SQL Server* using data type *Datetime2*.

This cannot be read as a date value in Access, thus the ODBC driver returns it as text which will be sorted as you show.

So either change the data type of the field to *Datetime* or, in your query, sort on the field converted to date:

```
Order By CDate([YourDateField])
```

or, if some records have Null values:

```
Order By CVDate([YourDateField])
```